# java removing whitespaces is also removing everything after the space

Tags: java, string, replaceall

why is `x.replaceAll("\\s+","")` is removing the first space and everything after it? if `x` was originally `a a` after doing `replaceAll()` and printing `x`, it only prints `a` not `aa`.

this is part of a larger project, but for testing purposes I tried it separately on a new java main file and still does the same thing this is the full complete program:

```
import java.util.*;
public class test {
    public static void main (String args[]){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String y = input.next();
        String x = y.replaceAll("\\s+","");
        System.out.println(x);      
}

}
```

Comment: I just tried it, I get `aa`. Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Just edited the question

Comment: Think i found the answer myself i should do nextLine() not just next() right?

Comment: Yes. That was the issue. Next time, for better help faster please post a MCVE to begin with. Also, you can use a debugger to help resolve issues with your code.

Comment: why not just use String.replace(" ", "") ? this would give the desired result without need of using that regex.

Answer (score 2):

By default Scanner uses one or more whitespaces as delimiter, and `next()` returns only one token between delimiters. So in case of input like `foo bar baz` `next()` will return `foo` another invocation of `next()` will return `baz` and another one `baz`.

If you wan to read entire line use `nextLine()` but [be careful when using it right after other `nextXyz()` methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods).

Answer (score 0):

Ok . Try this:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String y = input.nextLine();
        String x = y.replaceAll("\\s+","");
        System.out.println(x); 
    }
```

Use nextLine to get whole string.

Comment: Just edited the question

Comment: ["works for me"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118993/186652) is not really an answer. It is just comment suggesting that OP needs to provide more details.

Comment: @j.doe, edit code that takes a a and prints aa